# fetch instagram data for n8n for my new ulanzi pixel clock

Tags: javascript, node.js, n8n

I run node.js with n8n. Now my problem: If I enter the url: https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=chrisschwaab (my profile) it does not give any information about the follower count back.

I also tried to enter this url:
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/chrisschwaab/

Also without any result. What would be the right url to get the follower-count-data?

Thanks!
Chris

I tried this:
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/chrisschwaab/
and
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=chrisschwaab/